# Can I operate TLC5947 24-Channel, 12-Bit PWM LED Driver by just manipulating GPIO pins on Jetson Nano?

Tags: gpio, bit-bang, jetson

It is often written that Neopixels are not directly controllable by manipulating GPIO pins on  SBCs because the precise timings cannot be met, especially when from user space. I need somehow to drive the [TLC5947](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5947.pdf) that is a full color RGB LED driver taking the following signals:

- Data (SIN), a bit to read.
- Clock (SCLK), read a bit to display as currently represented by SIN.
- Move from shift register to display register (XLAT).

From the description looks like it only matters how do these signals  relate to each other. Hence I could set the SIN bit first, wait for a short time, then set the SCLK clock, wait, remove the SCLK clock, repeat. Even if my delay times vary slightly, should not actually matter as long as I keep the order which signal goes after what. Hence if my C++ program controls all 3 bits as separate GPIO lines (for instance, by writing into /sys/class/gpio/ as described [here](https://www.jetsonhacks.com/2019/06/07/jetson-nano-gpio/)) I hopefully could get without adding a separate Arduino board and the solving another complex problem how the board should communicate. Is it reasonable to expect this to work? 24 channels is not so many, it it would manage in a couple of seconds, should be ok.

From my search over web it looks there may be other (and likely "cleaner") ways to solve this problem but after two days of googling I have lost myself completely between all kinds of Python, Arduino, Neopixels and RPi. My device is Jetson Nano, my programming language is C++ and I need to drive my specific device. If anybody knows the alternative and better way to solve my problem, this would also be a great answer.

Another question about tlc5947 is [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/131277/tlc5947-led-driver-without-constantly-occupying-uc-pins). It is not closely relevant.

Comment: Your datasheet link points to a file on your local filesystem, and not a resource on the Internet. I added what I believe to be the correct link, can you double-check to make sure I got the right device?

Comment: The TLC5947 is for driving strings of LEDs that are not individually addressable, not for driving strings of addressable LEDs like Neopixels that get their individual RGB settings by clocking them in. I'm not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Yes, this, thanks a lot.

Comment: The goal is to drive a large (10 cm) 7 segment dual color LED indicators without any extra electronics inside. tlc5947 seems designed for that.

Comment: No Neopixels involved at all then?

Comment: No. The reason why I mentioned Neopixels is that Adafruit strongly advises against any bit banging from Linux SBC for them. They say cannot work. I just wanted to verify, maybe in my case it could work.

Comment: Neopixels are controlled in an entirely different way, so Adafruit's advice is not relevant for your application; what you want should be doable, see answer.

Comment: From reading the protocol description of the WS2812 it did not look very different to me while, indeed, tlc5947 seems watching for sync signals for every bit, just a shift register. Probably you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could do this.

The LED driver you describe has a synchronous serial configuration/data interface where timing requirements are mostly relative and minimum - typically with such a thing you can operate essentially as slowly as you like.   And this interface is quite decoupled from the actual PWM operation of the LEDs.

This is in contrast to single-wire "Neopixel" type interfaces where timing is critical to transmitting the data at all.  (Though there also exist other LED-string solutions which have both a clock and data line).

What you'll have to more deeply study the hardware and peripheral driver documentation to determine, is if there's any functional block in the Jetson's SoC which you could use to help transmit the data, for example an SPI engine, or perhaps a re-purposed I2S audio one, or some more generic synchronous serial engine.    Some SoC's also have MCU-like auxiliary processors which could handle tasks like this (potentially even driving Neopixels).  If you can feed the GPIO block with DMA, it may also be possible to setup a bitmapped "waveform" for the clock and data signals in memory and have that clocked out at a steady rate by the DMA engine (you'd probably have to represent at least a byte worth of channels, even though you'd only be using two pins, but on a board like this you have a lot of memory)

Particularly if you end up "bit-banging" this from software, your real concern may be not so much sending the data, but ensuring that the colors change at the times you want them to - especially if you are doing any audio/video type synchronization.  If you do end up bit-banging, you'll probably want to do the actual I/O twiddling in a kernel driver, not userspace.

At a practical level Adafruit sells a board with this chip, and they have a python-ish solution for driving it from a Raspberry Pi as part of a larger collection of gadget interface functionality.  It would appear that software collection has at least partial support for some Jetson boards, though you'll have to see for yourself if that includes your board, and if it includes the particular SPI functionality you'd need to operate this board in the way they operate it on a pi:

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Blinka/tree/master/src/adafruit_blinka/board/nvidia

Comment: This has been implemented and confirmed to work. There is no need to go to the kernel, writing into /sys as into file from the simple C++ code works well enough. I needed to solder a flat ribbon cable with each second pin grounded to get rid of the spurious errors on display, but this this cable everything works very well.